# How would you calculate the square you are jumping over on a checkerboard without using grid coordinates?

Tags: python, math, game-development

Here's the problem, standard checkerboard notation does not use grid positions, instead it uses the following (depending on board orientation):

```
Black player view
-----------------
   1   2   3   4
 5   6   7   8
   9  10  11  12
13  14  15  16
  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24
  25  26  27  28
29  30  31  32


White player view
-----------------
  32  31  30  29
28  27  26  25
  24  23  22  21
20  19  18  17
  16  15  14  13
12  11  10   9
   8   7   6   5
 4   3   2   1
```

When you make a legal capture (jump) move, you skip over a square. I need to determine, with math, what that square is 100% of the time under any direction (forward/back/left/right).

**For example, if there was a player on 2, an opponent on 7, and a blank space on 11, a player on 2 could jump to 11.**

**How would you calculate the following for ANY valid 2 move points on the board (and by ONLY having/knowing those 2 number values available):**

- **The middle square between any two points on the board**
- **Detecting if a move is jumping to the left or the right**
- **If move is at an edge as looping around is not allowed (e.g. 12 to 17 is not a valid move to end up on 13. But this is less important as I can figure that out I think..).**

I know I  will need to track if the move from is larger or smaller than the move to in order to get if a player is moving up or down the board. That's not the problem. I need the math to figure out the middle square and detect if the player is jumping left or right.

*And yes I know this would be MUCH easier if I used a coordinate system like A1 to C3. But all my code and data structures are written around standard checkers notation. I have tried stuff like multiplying by 4, subtracting 1, then re-multiplying by 4.. but this doesn't work in all cases or tell me direction. I guess if I checked if each was divisible by 2,3,4 (else 1) I could perform different math on each case.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated and here's a picture too if that helps:

[image: Checkers notation]

Comment: You must have already tried to code this - please edit your code attempt for each of your three calculations into your question. If you haven’t tried, well, StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service.

Comment: The arithmetic to figure out the moves on the board, using the standard notation, is fiddly, replete with `mod 4`s and `if`s, but no worse than fiddly.  Me, I'd avoid it altogther and build a 'jump' table to show all legal moves (eg `1->5`, `1->6`, ...), probably have separate tables for black and white, and another couple of tables for captures, etc.  That will take about an hour to set up and about 1kB of memory.  Actually I'd probably  have used a different representation of the board from the off but you don't seem to want to change that at this stage.

Comment: @barny, I'm not looking for code. I never asked for code. Nor did I ever mention a programming language. I'm looking for math, an algorithm or standard equation that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: @High Performance Mark - Thank you! This is much more helpful as it tells me there probably isn't a simple equation/algorithm to figure this out..

Comment: @High Performance Mark - I just realized I may have accidentally discovered a terrible whiteboard interview question.....

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I think what I'm going to do is make a dict of valid moves for one direction and then if they are going the other direction I'll just flip the key/values. Thanks again for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @HighPerformanceMark for a similar idea.

I decided that this is not super easy to do and there's no one equation to calculate. So I wrote two converter functions for translating stuff into and out of grid notation. This allows logic to be done based on coordinate systems and data storage and display to be done via checkers notation:

```
def notation_to_grid(number):
    coordinate_mapping = {1: 'G1', 2: 'E1', 3: 'C1', 4: 'A1',
                          5: 'H2', 6: 'F2', 7: 'D2', 8: 'B2',
                          9: 'G3', 10: 'E3', 11: 'C3', 12: 'A3',
                          13: 'H4', 14: 'F4', 15: 'D4', 16: 'B4',
                          17: 'G5', 18: 'E5', 19: 'C5', 20: 'A5',
                          21: 'H6', 22: 'F6', 23: 'D6', 24: 'B6',
                          25: 'G7', 26: 'E7', 27: 'C7', 28: 'A7',
                          29: 'H8', 30: 'F8', 31: 'D8', 32: 'B8'}

    return coordinate_mapping[number]


def grid_to_notation(coordinate):
    coordinate_mapping = {'G1': 1, 'E1': 2, 'C1': 3, 'A1': 4,
                          'H2': 5, 'F2': 6, 'D2': 7, 'B2': 8,
                          'G3': 9, 'E3': 10, 'C3': 11, 'A3': 12,
                          'H4': 13, 'F4': 14, 'D4': 15, 'B4': 16,
                          'G5': 17, 'E5': 18, 'C5': 19, 'A5': 20,
                          'H6': 21, 'F6': 22, 'D6': 23, 'B6': 24,
                          'G7': 25, 'E7': 26, 'C7': 27, 'A7': 28,
                          'H8': 29, 'F8': 30, 'D8': 31, 'B8': 32}

    return coordinate_mapping[coordinate.upper()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given two valid move points, a -> b,

First, take `k=(a-1)/4 mod 2` (where `/` is integer division). For instance:

```
(12-1)/4 | 2 = 11/4 | 2 = 2 | 2 = 0
(23-1)/4 | 2 = 22/4 | 2 = 5 | 2 = 1
```

(This tells whether the row is odd or even.)

As you know, if b>a, then it is a move up the board, and if b<a, then it is a move down the board.

if the difference between a and b is 7, it is a jump to the right; if the difference is 9, it is a jump to the left.

The jumped space is (a+b+1-2k)/2

Comment: I think you are close.. but unclear when to use the bigger value and get inconsistent results with some. Try 23 -> 32 for instance. I'm quite frequently getting floats back too.

move_from = 32
move_to = 23

move_from_factor = (move_from - 1) / 4 % 2
move_to_factor = (move_to - 1) / 4 % 2

middle_space = (move_from + move_to + 1 - 2 * move_from_factor) / 2

print(move_from)
print(move_to)
print(middle_space)

Comment: @DavidCahill: 23->32: moving up the board, (23-1)/4=5 (because integer division) so k=1, 32-23=9 so it's a jump to the left, (23+32+1-2)/2 = 54/2 = 27. I don't see the problem.